# How to achieve versioned WebApi at /api/v1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-areas

I want to build a versioned WebApi into an existing MVC project so that my URLs could be

```
/api/v1/account
/api/v2/account
```

I do not use Areas at the moment but after some research I thought this could work for me but apparently you cannot nest `Areas` (Im currently using MVC4 but can upgrade to 5).

How can I best achieve this?

**Update**

I ended up using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/08/using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are *two ways* to achieve versioning with Web API

**Method 1 :**

```
/api/accountv1/
/api/accountv2/
```

The simplest way I found in versioning your API is to create an identical controller of "*AccountV1Controller*" and name it "*AccountV2Controller*", notice the suffix V1 and V2 in controller name, we’ll depend on this part to select the appropriate controller based on API version.

**Method 2 :**

```
/api/v1/account
/api/v2/account
```

Or you could play with Routes to get the same behaviour

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "1-0Api",
    routeTemplate: "api/v1/Account/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "AccountV1", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "2-0Api",
    routeTemplate: "api/v2/Account/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "AccountV2", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Taken from [here](http://yassershaikh.com/achieving-versioning-web-api-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two approaches that would not require you to have 2 separate Controller classes.

---

**Request Headers**

One of the recommended versioning designs is to use request headers instead of URL parameters.

```
if (Request.Headers["API Version"] == "2")
{
    return Version2Code();
}
return Version1Code();
```

---

**Use a RouteContraint**

You could also use a route contraint too:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "versionedApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new {version = @"^[vV]\d+$"}
);
```

Then version would become a route function parameter just like id.

```
public class AccountController: Controller {

    public class ActionResult Index(object id, string version)
    {
       if (string.Equals(version, "v2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       {
          return Version2Code();
       }
       return Version1Code();
    }
}
```

---

**Also, check out Web API 2 Attribute Routing**

Also, if you do upgrade to Mvc 5 and WebAPI 2, there are examples of how to do this with Attribute Routing http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 0):

If you need API Versioning in ASP.NET Web API, the [Asp.Versioning.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Asp.Versioning.WebApi) (formerly [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning/)) is the most straight forward and robust option.

The simplest example is:

```cs
[ApiVersion( 1.0 )]
[Route( "api/example" )]
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/example?api-version=1.0
    public IHttpActionResult Get( ApiVersion apiVersion ) => ();
}
```

You can version your API any way you like, including by URL segment:

```cs
[ApiVersion( 1.0 )]
[RoutePrefix( "api/v{version:apiVersion}/example" )]
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/v{version}/helloworld
    [Route]
    public IHttpActionResult Get() => Ok();
}
```

You're setup would then look something like:

```cs
public void Configuration( HttpConfiguration configuration )
{
    // only required when versioning by url: ~/v{apiVersion}/{controller}
    var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver()
    { 
        ConstraintMap = { ["apiVersion"] = typeof( ApiVersionRouteConstraint ) },
    };

    // reporting api versions will return the headers
    // "api-supported-versions" and "api-deprecated-versions"
    configuration.AddApiVersioning( options => options.ReportApiVersions = true );
    configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes( constraintResolver );
}
```

Most applications now use *Direct Routing* (aka *Attribute Routing*), but if you want to use *Convention Routing*, that is supported is well.

> Mixing routing methods is not recommended, however, due to limitations in the ASP.NET Web API routing system.